# Using Dapper to map to nested objects not working

Tags: c#, dapper

**The Problem**

Simply put, the mapping does not perform as expected. The local variable `reason` comes back as null so the assignment to `nav` sets the nested object `Reason` to null as well.

Am I missing something simple here?

**The Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PA].[spGetDocumentNavById]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@DocumentNavID INT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT
    dn.DocumentNavID,
    dn.IssuerName,
    nt.Name,
    dn.Amount,
    dn.BTF,
    dn.NavDate,
    dn.ReceivedDate,
    dn.PrimaryIdentifier,
    dn.AssetID,
    dh.LastModifiedBy,
    dh.IsApproved,
    dh.Corrected,
    dh.ReasonID
FROM PA.DocumentNavs dn WITH(NOLOCK)
    JOIN PA.NAVTypes nt WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON nt.NAVTypeID = dn.NavTypeID
    LEFT JOIN PA.DocumentsHistory dh WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON dh.DocumentID = dn.DocumentID
    LEFT JOIN PA.Analysts a WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON a.AnalystID = dh.LastModifiedBy
WHERE dn.DocumentNavID = @DocumentNavID
```

**The C#**

```
public DocumentNav FindById(int documentNavId)
    {
        var data = new
        {
            documentNavId
        };

        using (var conn = SqlConnection)
        {
            var response = conn.Query<DocumentNav, Reason, DocumentNav>("[PA].spGetDocumentNavById",
                map: (nav, reason) =>
                {
                    nav.Reason = reason;
                    return nav;
                }, param: data, splitOn: "ReasonID", commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                .DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault();

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which properties are meant to map to `DocumentNav`? and which to `Reason`? I can't see the `DocumentNav` or `Reason` definitions, so I don't want to make assumptions... (and it really isn't obvious from the columns)

Answer (score 0):

Dapper is able to split the returned row query by Id columns ("Id" or "id"). If your primary key is different or you would like to split the row at a point other than Id, use the optional "splitOn" parameter.
In your example the query should look like:

```
SELECT
    -- DocumentNav Object Columns 
    dn.DocumentNavID AS "Id",
    dn.IssuerName,
    -- ... all other DocumentNav properties..
    -- Reason Object Columns
    dh.ReasonID AS "Id"
    dh.LastModifiedBy,
    dh.IsApproved,
    dh.Corrected
    -- ... all other Reason properties..
FROM PA.DocumentNavs dn WITH(NOLOCK)
    JOIN PA.NAVTypes nt WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON nt.NAVTypeID = dn.NavTypeID
    LEFT JOIN PA.DocumentsHistory dh WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON dh.DocumentID = dn.DocumentID
    LEFT JOIN PA.Analysts a WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON a.AnalystID = dh.LastModifiedBy
WHERE dn.DocumentNavID = @DocumentNavID
```

You need your objects to be with property name "Id" (DocumentNav & Reason)